# How can I merge effect interpreters when using a library like freer-simple?

Tags: haskell, free-monad

I am playing around with [freer-simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-simple-1.1.0.0) and trying to work out how to combine effects.

I have an algebra to represent a simple file system and user invoked failure as follows:

```
data FileSystem r where
  ReadFile :: Path a File -> FileSystem String
  WriteFile :: Path a File -> String -> FileSystem ()

readFile :: Member FileSystem effs => Path a File -> Eff effs String
readFile = send . ReadFile

writeFile :: Member FileSystem effs => Path a File -> String -> Eff effs ()
writeFile pth = send . WriteFile pth

data AppError r where
  Ensure :: Bool -> String -> AppError ()
  Fail :: String -> AppError ()

ensure :: Member AppError effs => Bool -> String -> Eff effs ()
ensure condition message = send $ Ensure condition message

fail :: Member AppError effs =>  String -> Eff effs ()
fail = send . Fail
```

And an "application" in a function called interactor as follows:

```
data TestItem = Item {
  pre :: String,
  post :: String,
  path :: Path Abs File
}

data RunConfig = RunConfig {
  environment :: String,
  depth :: Integer,
  path :: Path Abs File
}

type FileSys r = (Member FileSystem r)
type AppFailure r = (Member AppError r)

interactor :: TestItem -> RunConfig -> (AppFailure r, FileSys r) => Eff r ApState
interactor item runConfig = do
                              let fullFilePath = path (runConfig :: RunConfig)
                              writeFile fullFilePath $ pre item  <> post item
                              fail "random error ~ its a glitch"
                              txt <- readFile [absfile|C:\Vids\SystemDesign\Wrong.txt|]
                              pure $ ApState fullFilePath txt
```

At this stage I am only interested in dumb "documentation" interpreters that log the steps, I don't even care
what failing would do in terms of control flow:

```
fileSystemDocInterpreter :: FileSystem ~> Eff '[Writer [String], effs]
fileSystemDocInterpreter = 
     let
        mockContents = "Mock File Contents"
      in
        \case
          ReadFile path -> tell ["readFile: " <> show path] $> mockContents
          WriteFile path str -> tell ["write file: " <>
                                        show path <>
                                        "\nContents:\n" <>
                                        str]

errorDocInterpreter :: AppError ~> Eff '[Writer [String]]
errorDocInterpreter = \case
                    Ensure condition errMsg -> tell [condition ? "Ensure Check Passed" $
                      "Ensure Check Failed ~ " <>  errMsg]
                    Fail errMsg -> tell ["Failure ~ " <>  errMsg]
```

The combined interpreter is as follows:

```
type FileSys r = (Member FileSystem r)
type AppFailure r = (Member AppError r)

executeDocumented :: forall a. Eff '[FileSystem, AppError] a -> ((a, [String]), [String])
executeDocumented app = run $ runWriter 
                            $ reinterpret errorDocInterpreter 
                            $ runWriter 
                            $ reinterpret fileSystemDocInterpreter app
```

When I run this with sample configs I get something like the following:

```
((ApState {
            filePath = "C:\\Vids\\SystemDesign\\VidList.txt", 
            fileText = "Mock File Contents"
          },
          ["write file: \"C:\\\\Vids\\\\SystemDesign\\\\VidList.txt\
                        "\nContents: I do a test the test runs",
          "readFile: \"C:\\\\Vids\\\\SystemDesign\\\\Wrong.txt\""]
         ),
         ["Failure ~ random error ~ its a glitch"]
 )
```

I have a couple of questions about the interpreters above:

1. The order this to compile I had to make the types as follows:

   ```
   fileSystemDocInterpreter :: FileSystem ~> Eff '[Writer [String], effs] 

   errorDocInterpreter :: AppError ~> Eff '[Writer [String]]
   ```

   and call `errorDocInterpreter` after `fileSystemDocInterpreter` because the 
   `fileSystemDocInterpreter` has trailing effs and `errorDocInterpreter` doesn't.

   Is there a way to change the type signatures or invoke these so it wouldn't matter 
   which was needed first by the parent interpreter?
2. Both fileSystemDocInterpreter and errorDocInterpreter use the Writer [String] effect.
   Is there a way to combine these so runWriter is only called once so the failure and file system
   messages appear in one log?

Comment: As for (2), perhaps you could use `subsume` to merge two `Writer` layers.

Comment: As for (1), does writing the interpreters like `fileSystemDocInterpreter :: FileSystem ~> Eff ((Writer [String]) ': effs)` help things? The idea is that `effs` is a list of effects which might or might not be empty.

Comment: @danidiaz your suggestion for 1 works perfectly: `AppError ~> Eff (Writer [String] ': effs)` and `FileSystem ~> Eff (Writer [String] ': effs)`. Will have a look at `susume` tomorrow

Comment: Come to think of it, using `Member` constraints is even more flexible because that way the writer can be anywhere in the type-level list. Also, `subsume` might not be necessary after all in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [`Eff`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-simple-1.1.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Freer.html#t:Eff) type states that

> Normally, a concrete list of effects is not used to parameterize Eff. Instead, the Member or Members constraints are used to express constraints on the list of effects without coupling a computation to a concrete list of effects.

Therefore, in order to maximize flexibility we could change the signatures of `fileSystemDocInterpreter` and `errorDocInterpreter` to:

```
fileSystemDocInterpreter :: Member (Writer [String]) effs => FileSystem ~> Eff effs

errorDocInterpreter :: Member (Writer [String]) effs => AppError ~> Eff effs
```

We don't really care *where* the `Writer [String]` is on the type-level list, of if there are any more effects on the list. We just need  `Writer [String]` to be there. This change takes care of (1).

As for (2), we could define `executeDocumented` as follows:

```
executeDocumented :: forall a. Eff '[FileSystem, AppError, Writer [String]] a 
                  -> (a, [String])
executeDocumented app = run $ runWriter
                            $ interpret errorDocInterpreter
                            $ interpret fileSystemDocInterpreter
                            $ app
```

Here we are making use in the interpreter of the flexibility we gained when defining the computations. We put a `Writer [String]` at the end of the list, and the two `interpret`s send `FileSystem` and `AppError`s effects to the writer. No need to have separate `Writer [String]` layers! (That said, if at other occasion we have two effects of the same type at the front of the list, we can use [`subsume`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-simple-1.1.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Freer.html#v:subsume) to remove the duplication.)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to restore a source code to watch how it works

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MonoLocalBinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Data.Functor
import Data.List
import Data.String
import Control.Natural (type (~>))
import Control.Monad.Freer.Writer (Writer, tell,runWriter)
import Control.Monad.Freer
  (
    Eff
  , LastMember
  , Member
  , interpret
  , interpretM
  , send
  , run
  , runM
  )

data FileSystem r where
  ReadFile :: FilePath  -> FileSystem String
  WriteFile :: FilePath -> String -> FileSystem ()

readFile :: Member FileSystem effs => FilePath -> Eff effs String
readFile = send . ReadFile

writeFile :: Member FileSystem effs => FilePath -> String -> Eff effs ()
writeFile pth = send . WriteFile pth

data AppError r where
  Ensure :: Bool -> String -> AppError ()
  Fail :: String -> AppError ()

ensure :: Member AppError effs => Bool -> String -> Eff effs ()
ensure condition message = send $ Ensure condition message

fail :: Member AppError effs =>  String -> Eff effs ()
fail = send . Fail

data ApState = ApState {filePath::String,fileText::String} deriving Show

data TestItem = Item {
  pre :: String,
  post :: String,
  pathTI :: FilePath
}

data RunConfig = RunConfig {
  environment :: String,
  depth :: Integer,
  pathRC :: FilePath
}

type FileSys r = (Member FileSystem r)
type AppFailure r = (Member AppError r)

interactor :: TestItem -> RunConfig -> (AppFailure r, FileSys r) => Eff r ApState
interactor item runConfig = do
                              let fullFilePath = pathRC (runConfig :: RunConfig)
                              Main.writeFile fullFilePath $ pre item  <> post item
                              Main.fail "random error ~ its a glitch"
                              txt <- Main.readFile "C:\\Vids\\SystemDesign\\Wrong.txt"
                              pure $ ApState fullFilePath txt

fileSystemDocInterpreter :: Member (Writer [String]) effs => FileSystem ~> Eff effs
fileSystemDocInterpreter =
     let
        mockContents::String = "Mock File Contents"
      in
        \case
          ReadFile path -> tell ["readFile: " <> show path] $> mockContents
          WriteFile path str -> tell ["write file: " <>
                                        show path <>
                                        "\nContents:\n" <>
                                        str]

errorDocInterpreter :: Member (Writer [String]) effs => AppError ~> Eff effs
errorDocInterpreter = \case
       Ensure condition errMsg -> tell [if condition then "Ensure Check Passed" else ("Ensure Check Failed ~ " <>  errMsg) ]
       Fail errMsg -> tell ["Failure ~ " <>  errMsg]

executeDocumented :: forall a. Eff '[FileSystem, AppError, Writer [String]] a
                  -> (a, [String])
executeDocumented app = run $ runWriter
                            $ interpret errorDocInterpreter
                            $ interpret fileSystemDocInterpreter
                            $ app

main :: IO ()
main = do
   let ti = Item {pre="", post ="", pathTI =""}
   let rc = RunConfig {environment ="", depth =1, pathRC ="C:\\Vids\\SystemDesign\\VidList.txt"}
   let (apst,messages) = executeDocumented $ interactor ti rc
   putStrLn $ show apst
   mapM_ (\x->putStrLn x) messages
   putStrLn "_"
```

Comment: This does not answer OPs question